# C# Factory pattern with Abstract and Internal Constructor, under Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abstract-class, factory-pattern, internal

In my mind is the `Microsoft.ServiceBus QueueClient`

So the `QueueClient` is abstract class, with an Internal Constructor; We call `QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(...)` to get either AMQP or SBMP concrete client class. That's the only way to get an instance of `QueueClient`.

I can understand why they use this pattern given the `ConnectionString` specify lots of details.

But under Unit test, this `QueueClient` is hard to mock, (at least Moq can't do it); even with Microsoft Fakes, the `ShimQueueClient` is only a wrapper with some methods you can setup, but you can't new it or pass it as parameter downstream.

My question is when you decided to use this kind of Pattern for whatever reason, what can you do to make it more friendly to tests?

Something I can think of like you can have a static method allow you to `QueueClient.CreateForTest()`, but feel weird about this; or make this `QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString` to take dummy string (which I already did by give it a very short 'correct' string, with the cost of some catched exceptions you can see within IntelliTrace).

(note: I'm not really asking that one should create your own `IQueueClient` etc.)

Thanks a lot.

Dong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create a base interface to back this pattern. Your abstract class with internal constructor would implement this interface, making it flexible for faking, moqing and substitution.

In the case of `Microsoft.ServiceBus QueueClient`, I would [decorate](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) it with my own interface implementation in production code so that i can fake the decorator in the unit tests.

Comment: In the QueueClient case, the signature of it is this:  `public abstract class QueueClient : MessageClientEntity, IMessageSessionEntity, IMessageSender, IMessageReceiver, IMessageBrowser`  Do you mean then you should have an IQueueClient which includes all these then you do `QueueClient : IQueueClient`? Would also like to know if THIS is a good pattern as well.

Comment: @Xied yes to both questions. See IList. `public interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable`. Allows an `IList` to be used where an object that implements `ICollection` *and* `IEnumerable` is required.

Comment: BTW we can't inherit from QueueClient because two methods of it are `internal abstract`.

Comment: @Xied You need to _decorate_ QueueClient using the decorator or adaptor pattern